# Python Object definition

Tags: python, oop, object, instantiation

This should be easy, but for I am missing something.

I have an object that works exactly as I expect.

```
class TextElement(ContentItemElement):
    '''
    Single String Elements, for example, headlines
    '''
    def __init__(self, name, data):
       super(TextElement, self).__init__()
       self.name=name
       self.text=data


    def prettyPrint(self):
        printstring =  u'*HTML* '
        self.name.encode('utf-8')
        printstring += u'<h3> '+self.name+u' </h3>'
        self.text.encode('utf-8')
        printstring += u'<p> '+self.text+u' </h3>'
        print printstring
```

Ok, great, I can instantiate that, and it does exactly what I want it to.  But I really would like to create a more specific version of TextObjects. so I do this:

```
class CiteElement(TextElement):
    '''
    Single String Elements, for example, headlines
    '''
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        super(CiteElement, self).__init__()
        self.validValues=['Crap I make up', 'Crap I found on the web']
```

but when I try to instantiate it, this works:

```
ee = TextElement(element, self.raw[element])
ee.validValues=['Crap I make up', 'Crap I found on the web']
```

but this Does not

```
ee = CiteElement(element, self.raw[element])
```

Instead giving me this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Obviously I am missing something small.  Something key to python objects.  Something I should darn well know, but have been coding around for years.  But what is it?

Comment: fix your indentation of your code inside the class

Comment: Sorry, that's stack, not my code.  Fixed.

Comment: @SkipHuffman -- Not quite fixed.  Your docstrings are still out of alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the constructor of your base class is defined as

```
def __init__(self, name, data):
....
```

And you are calling it without parameters from your derived class.

```
def __init__(self, name, data):
    super(CiteElement, self).__init__()
```

Comment: I *never* win these answer-races!  In your face!  In your face!

Comment: Yeah, but yours has a bit more detail of what mistake I made, not just how to correct it.

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
super(CiteElement, self).__init__()
```

should be

```
super(CiteElement, self).__init__(name, data)
```

Comment: Ah, because I need to pass that information on to the parent object?

Comment: Yup.  It needs those for parent-init; it cannot make the connection just because the parameters have the same name.

Comment: What you need to pass to your parent is up to you...you are designing your application. When your parent constructor *requires* parameters then you need to pass them, obviously.

Comment: Right, that is what I was asking.  I knew I was close to what I wanted.